# ListView Perde O foco ao voltar

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma lista de Produtos, quando pressiono no produto número 50 por exemplo sou redirecionado para a tela de detalhes de produtos ao pressionar em voltar a lista perde o foco e volta ao topo, queria saber como fazer pra pegar a posição do item que foi pressionado para quando clicar ele voltar para o item da lista que selecionei:

Minha lista:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Detalhes:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem vindo! Por favor, sugerimos que [realize um tour pelo site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e veja Como criar um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável!](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Assim, facilita a comunidade a te ajudar!

Comment: Você mata a activity que está a lista?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma opção seria você salvar o *index* e a posição do primeiro item da lista antes de ir para o *layout* de detalhes, isso se não estiver finalizando a tela de itens. O motivo de estar perdendo a posição, talvez seja porque no `onResume` da tela de itens, esteja consultando novamente a lista (verifique isso). Veja então como seria:

```
int index = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View v = listview.getChildAt(0);
int itemTop = (v == null) ? 0 : (v.getTop() - listview.getPaddingTop());
```

Para restaurar, você pode usar o método `setSelectionFromTop` em seu `onResume()`:

```
listview.setSelectionFromTop(index, itemTop);
```

Veja [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035521/2570426) no SOen.

---

Outra opção seria salvar o estado usando [`Parcelable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html). Explorando o ciclo de vida da *activity*, você usa o `onPause` para que no momento em que você sair da atividade, salvar o estado usando [`onSaveInstanceState`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) relação a lista. Veja um exemplo:

```
Parcelable state;

@Override
public void onPause() {    
    state = listview.onSaveInstanceState();
    super.onPause();
}
```

Para restaurar, verifique antes se há um estado salvo, um exemplo, se foi atribuído um valor a variável `state`. Logo depois, use o método [`onRestoreInstanceState`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) passando como parâmetro o estado. Veja:

```
if(state != null) {
    listview.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
}
```